# Auditable encrypted ledger

Tags: cr.crypto-security, homomorphic-encryption

Consider a cloud-based accounting system that needs access to aggregate information such as an account's balance but doesn't need access to individual transaction amounts in a ledger.

Does there exist a homomorphic encryption scheme that allows a public observer (such as a cloud computing provider) to compute the *plaintext* sum of a set of encrypted unsigned integers without being able to decode any individual transaction value (n=1 notwithstanding)?

As another example, regulations exist to ensure capital reserves. An institution could use such a scheme to furnish proof of compliance without disclosing individual transactions.

Comment: With "plaintext sum" do you mean that the public server is able to "decode only the result of the *sum* of the encrypted integers (*sum* allowed by adopting the homomorphic encryption)" ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: It would be interesting to know if such a system exist for non-arbitrary intervals. For example the customer may allow the decryption of $n_4$ and $n_9$ only, so the accountant could calculate the difference $n_9 - n_4$ but not arbitrary differences. In this way the steps that led to the sum would still be concealed.

Comment: maybe this belongs to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Diego, the question is in the scope as explained in the [FAQ].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all non-negative integers $n_0$,$n_1$,$n_2$ and random strings $r_0,r_1,r_2$

$n_0 \:\: = \:\: (n_0+n_1+n_2)-(n_1+n_2)$

$=$
$\operatorname{plaintextsum}(\operatorname{encrypt}(n_0,r_0),\operatorname{encrypt}(n_1,r_1),\operatorname{encrypt}(n_2,r_2))$

$- \: \operatorname{plaintextsum}(\operatorname{encrypt}(n_1,r_1),\operatorname{encrypt}(n_2,r_2))$

.

Therefore any such scheme would be completely insecure

if more than 2 non-negative integers are encrypted with it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea could work. The cyphertext would need to come with a non-interactive 
zero-knowledge proof that the plaintext lies in a certain interval ([0,100] for example) See link below for more details.

It is important to note that the answer at the end needs to be decrypted so it requires use of a decryption oracle at least once. Threshold encryption might be useful here.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.4029&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I will read up on that citation.